# Generate an ID from different column choices in Microsoft Access 2013

Tags: ms-access

So I'm putting together a Database for my father's company and sadly I didn't pay much attention in class when we were going over access. My father has explained his old database to me and want's something similar to it. One of these functions that he wants is the ability to choose different options (lets say from 5 different columns) then have an ID created depending on what choices he made. So if I was adding a pizza to the database and I wanted:

1. Thin Crust
2. Cheese
3. Ham
4. Bacon
5. Pepperoni

Then the generated ID would look something like: "TCCHBP"

I'm not looking to be spoon fed and honestly I'm usually quite good at finding what I need online but I haven't been able to dig up any tutorials sadly. If anyone could point me in the right direction or post a tutorial link that would be most appreciated.

Thank ypu for taking the time to read and help.

Answer (score 0):

In Access_2013, if the "options" are indeed just Yes/No fields in the table then for the "code" you could simply create a Calculated field, like this:

[image: table definition showing calculated field]